# LinkedBlockingQueue and worker threads - is this code thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to understand if the below is thread safe, it was written by another developer whose code I have inherited and is no longer with us.

I have a BaseProvider class that is actually a message cache, represented by a LinkedBlockingQueue. This class stores incoming messages in the queue.

I have a set of worker threads that read of this queue. As such the LinkedBlockingQueue is thread safe.

Questions
1. When the worker thread calls provider.getNextQueuedItem(), the provider goes through item by item and adds it to a list and returns the list of messages. While it is doing this, what happens if there is a message added to the provider class by calling addToQueue? Does the takeLock internal to the LinkedBlockingQueue prevent from adding a new message to the queue until all messages are taken off the queue?

2. As you would notice, each worker thread has access to all the providers, so while one worker thread is going through all the providers and calls getNextQueuedItem() , what happens when another worker thread also calls through all the providers and calls getNextQueuedItem()? Would both the worker threads be stepping over each other?

   public abstract class BaseProvider implements IProvider {

   ```
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<CoreMessage> internalQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<CoreMessage>();

   @Override
   public synchronized List<CoreMessage> getNextQueuedItem() {
       List<CoreMessage> arrMessages = new ArrayList<CoreMessage>();                    
       if (internalQueue.size() > 0) {
           Logger.debug("Queue has entries");    
           CoreMessage msg = null;
           try {
               msg = internalQueue.take();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               Logger.warn("Interruption");
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           if (msg != null) {
               arrMessages.add(msg);
           }
       }
       return arrMessages;
   }

   protected synchronized void addToQueue(CoreMessage message) {
       try {
           internalQueue.put(message);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           Logger.error("Exception adding message to queue " + message);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

// There are a set of worker threads that read through these queues

```
public class Worker implements Runnable 
 @Override
 public void run() {
    Logger.info("Worker - Running Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    while (!stopRequested) {
        boolean processedMessage = false;
        for (IProvider provider : providers) {
            List<CoreMessage> messages = provider.getNextQueuedItem();
            if (messages == null || messages.size() != 0) {
                processedMessage = true;
                for (CoreMessage message : messages) {
                    final Message msg = createEndurMessage(provider, message);
                    processMessage(msg);
                    message.commit();
                }
            }
        }
        if (!(processedMessage || stopRequested)) {
            // this is to stop the thread from spinning when there are no messages
            try {
                Thread.sleep(WAIT_INTERVAL);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does `getNextQueuedItem()` return a list of one message? Why does it not simply return the message?

Comment: Re, `if (messages == null || messages.size() != 0) ...` Not clear what the author was attempting to say here, but it doesn't matter because `messages` can never be `null`: The `getNextQueueItem()` method _always_ returns a `List`, which may contain either zero or one items.  Also, there's probably no reason to explicitly test the size of the `messages` list either because the `for (...)` loop is going to test it anyway.

Comment: Re, "When the worker thread calls `provider.getNextQueuedItem()`, the provider goes through item by item..." That does not appear to be true. The implementation of `getNextQueuedItem()` in your example does nothing but take _one_ item from `internalQueue`, and then it returns that single item wrapped up in a `new  ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what happens if there is a message added to the provider class by calling addToQueue?

`getNextQueuedItem()` and `addToQueue(...)` are both `synchronized` methods.  If those are the only two methods that access the `private ... internalQueue`, then there is no way in which multiple threads could ever access `internalQueue` at the same time.

> while one worker thread is going through all the providers and calls getNextQueuedItem() , what happens when another worker thread also calls through all the providers and calls getNextQueuedItem()?

Are you asking about multiple workers accessing the *same* provider? That can't happen because `getNextQueuedItem()` is a `synchronized` method.

-- OR --

Are you asking about different workers accessing *different* providers? That should not matter (at least, not as far as the `BaseProvider` class is concerned) because there does not appear to be any way in which the different objects could be connected with each other.

Comment: Thanks for your response @solmon-slow . I have an additional question -  message.commit(); is being called after process message. Now if two worker threads have picked up messages from the provider, and the first worker is taking time to process the first message, meanwhile the second worker thread has finished processing the second message and sent the ack for the message. Since the first message is still not acked, while the second message is acked would that keep the second message still on the queue until the first message is acked.

Comment: @serah, Re, "...would that keep the second message still on the queue until the first message is acked." What queue are you asking about? If you are talking about the `internalQueue` in your code example, then `msg=internalQueue.take()` removes an item from the queue. End of story. If you are asking about some other queue, then that's not shown in your example, and you probably should start a new question for it.

Comment: Thanks, I already did raise one, just after commenting here realized this requires a new thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489314/do-messages-on-a-solace-queue-need-to-be-acked-in-the-order-they-are-on-the-queu